# colloquial expression for a chewing gum

Tags: vocabulaire

What is a colloquial expression for a chewing gum in French?

I know that the formal one is "gomme à mâcher f".

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In France, we just say "un chewing-gum", as far as I know. I never heard of any more colloquial expressions for them.

You can see that [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chewing-gum) simply uses "chewing-gum" all over the place :

> Des études ont montré que le chewing-gum peut améliorer l'humeur de celui qui en consomme<sup>[réf. nécessaire]</sup>.

In Québec, people say "*une gomme*". Some other expressions (*chiclette*, *chique*) are used in other french-speaking places, but I never heard them in France.

Answer (score 2):

A colloquial term used to be an 'apocope' where the -gum part is not pronounced, and the  *chewing* pronunciation is frenchized. Something that sounds a bit like: un **chou-in'g**, or better **/ʃwiŋ[ə]/** (thanks to @jlliagre).

> tu me files un chou-in'g ?

I don't know if it is still in use very often. Some have tried to propose the term "mâchouillon", but that did not work.

Comment: En phonétique plutot /ʃwiŋ[ə]/ que /ʃu.ɛ̃gə/

Comment: Oui, bien sûr !

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, we use "une gomme" for a chewing gum in Quebec.  There are also Anglicism like in France where they simply say "chewing-gum", mais ça dépends seulement de ce que vous preferez.